# Is there any alternative to do this except the PIVOT?

Tags: sql

I have this table here,

**Options**

```
ID      sType   hValue
1       Late    10
2       NSF     20
```

Now what I want is, a single query to get an output like below:

```
Late  NSF
10    20
```

2 separate columns with their respective hValues (in a single row). And should have separate column names so that I can use this query to Join with some other data.

I have tried Case statements But obviously it doesnt work. It gives me 2 separate rows with 1 NULL value in each column.

```
select Case when sType = 'Late' Then hValue End late,
Case When sType='NSF' Then hValue End nsf
from Options
where sType IN ('Late', 'NSF')
```

Comment: What database system is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Max` aggregate on top of your `case` statement

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN sType = 'Late' THEN hValue END) late,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sType = 'NSF' THEN hValue END) nsf
FROM Options
WHERE sType IN ('Late', 'NSF')
```

Considering that your `'Late'` or `'NSF'` will not be duplicated

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

PIVOT is just a shortcut of some other SQL statements. In most case, for PIVOT statement

```
-- Copied from T-SQL 2012 Fundamental.
SELECT ...
FROM <source_table_or_table_expression>
PIVOT(<agg_func>(<aggregation_element>)
FOR <spreading_element>
IN (<list_of_target_columns>)) AS <result_table_alias>;
```

it can be converted to

```
SELECT pass_through_columns,
    <agg_func>(CASE WHEN <spreading_element> = '<target_columns1>' WHEN aggregation_element END) AS target_column1,
    <agg_func>(CASE WHEN <spreading_element> = '<target_columns2>' WHEN aggregation_element END) AS target_column2,
    ...
FROM <source_table_or_table_expression>
GROUP BY pass_through_columns;
```

You can't talk PIVOT without aggregation function. In you case, try

```
select MAX(Case when sType = 'Late' Then hValue End) AS  late,
MAX(Case When sType='NSF' Then hValue End) nsf
from Options
where sType IN ('Late', 'NSF')
```

There might be distinct value for each spreading_element (Late, NSF), which makes MAX redundant,  but it is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

Or using ugly hard-coded subquery, yet it is simple

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT hValue FROM Options WHERE sType = 'Late') AS Late, 
    (SELECT hValue FROM Options WHERE sType = 'NSF') AS NSF
```

Comment: Works well as long the table only has max one Late row, and one NSF row.

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server, you can use a dynamic query. This will work well with more than 2 records and no values are hardcoded.

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(max) = N'select '
select @sql = @sql + cast(hValue as nvarchar(50)) + ' as ' + '''' + sType + ''', ' 
from Options

if len(@sql) > 2
   set @sql = left(@sql, len(@sql) - 1)

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c35b1/5)

You may need to modified the query slightly as I assumed the data types.

If you need to further join to the output, you can dump it into a temp table.